# When is constructor called for a static object

Tags: c++

I understand that static variables are initialized at compile time, but what about a static object?

e.g. if I have the following code:

```
class A {
    A();
};

A::A(){
    std::cout << "Constructing A" << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    static A A_obj;
    std::cout << "Goodbye cruel world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Should I expect the output to be:

```
Hello World!
Constructing A
Goodbye cruel world
```

or

```
Constructing A
Hello World!
Goodbye cruel world
```

Comment: What do you get when you run the code?

Comment: You should get your first output.

Comment: See __Static local variables__ in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables):

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier static **have static storage duration but are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration** (unless their initialization is zero- or constant-initialization, which can be performed before the block is first entered). On all further calls, the declaration is skipped.

Meaning the constructor is called as soon as the declaration is seen for the class. Furthermore:

> The **destructor for a block-scope static variable is called at program exit**, but only if the initialization took place successfully.

Since the program exit is at the end of the function `main()`, once your program reaches the end of `main()`, the destructor of your class will be called.

Thus, you should expect the first output for the program.

Answer (score 9):

> "I understand that static variables are initialized at compile time"

Not true. `static` variables at function scope are strictly initialised at the point of first encounter. And will be destructed after the closing brace of `main`.

You'll get output in this order:

```
Hello World!
Constructing A
Goodbye cruel world
```

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that static variables are initialized at compile time, but what about a static object?

That's an incorrect understanding.

Any variable, `static` or not, can be evaluated at compile time if that's possible. Some are required to be evaluated at compile time. Some cannot be evaluated at compile time, and hence must be initialized at run time. Once again, that does not depend on whether a variable is `static` or not.

Coming to your code, you should expect the first block of output.

The code to initialize `A_obj` is executed after the previous line has been executed.